# Python & Multilevel JSON File read and add

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to read the following JSON file and update it, specifically:

1. I can get the latest data analysis (`var: lastAnalysisCompleted`) was completed using `get_json()`
2. I get the following error code "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when attempting to set baselineDictionaryFilename variable
3. I want to create a new grouping under the 'analysis' using the `write_json()` module. But running into errors.

How can I proceed?

```
        New grouping:
        "01-02-2020":{
            "dictionaryFileName": "Dictionary_01-02-2020.json",
            "analysisFileName": "Analysis_Output_01-02-2020.xlsx",
            "netNewLabelledEntries": "10",
            "range90": "1",
            "range80": "3",
            "range75":"1",
            "rangeLessThan75":"5"
            }


    def get_json():
    with open(jFile, 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()

    # parse file
    obj = json.loads(data)

    #secret = parsed_input['secret']
    lastAnalysisCompleted = obj['lastAnalysisCompleted']

    baselineDictionaryFileName = obj['analysis'][lastAnalysisCompleted]['dictionaryFileName']
```

Here is the module I wrote to update JSON but it doesn't work

```
def write_json(filename=jFile):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=3)

with open(jFile) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    temp = data['analysis']

    y = {
        "01-02-2020":{
            "dictionaryFileName": "Dictionary_01-02-2020.json",
            "analysisFileName": "Analysis_Output_01-02-2020.xlsx",
            "netNewLabelledEntries": "10",
            "range90": "1",
            "range80": "3",
            "range75":"1",
            "rangeLessThan75":"5"
        }
    }

    temp.append(y)

write_json(data)
```

Here is my JSON file.

```
{   
    "lastAnalysisCompleted": "01-01-2020",
    "analysis":[
        {
        "12-31-2019":{
            "dictionaryFileName": "Dictionary_12-31-2019.json",
            "analysisFileName": "Analysis_Output_12-31-2019.xlsx",
            "netNewLabelledEntries": "10",
            "range90": "1",
            "range80": "3",
            "range75":"1",
            "rangeLessThan75":"5"
            },
        "01-01-2020":{
            "dictionaryFileName": "Dictionary_01-01-2020.json",
            "analysisFileName": "Analysis_Output_01-01-2020.xlsx",
            "netNewLabelledEntries": "10",
            "range90": "1",
            "range80": "3",
            "range75":"1",
            "rangeLessThan75":"5"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to do #2 using the following code:

return obj['analysis'][0][lastAnalysisCompleted]['dictionaryFileName']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code for getting the file name it is array of dicts you need to use index to access specific dictionary.

```
def get_json():
    with open('test.json', 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()

    # parse file
    obj = json.loads(data)

    #secret = parsed_input['secret']
    lastAnalysisCompleted = obj['lastAnalysisCompleted']

    baselineDictionaryFileName = ''.join([d[lastAnalysisCompleted]['dictionaryFileName'] for d in obj['analysis'] if lastAnalysisCompleted in d])
```

And for writing to json file you are passing data to `write_json()` function and in function you are not defined argument for `data`

```
def write_json(data, filename=jFile):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=3)
```